# Hacer dos menus a partir de dos botones en HTML usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Se necesita imprimir en una misma vista dos botones, que al pulsarlos mostrarán un menu cada uno. El menu que muestre cada uno será distinto. El unico elemento que comparten estos dos menus es un estilo css.

Comment: Puedes facilitar el código que tienes realizado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! agregale un valor aleatorio a cada fila y luego ordena por el mismo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías probar con dos funciones distintas en JavaScript, una para cada boton, cuya finalidad sea imprimir en un elemento div el menú. Por ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    /*Añado un estilo a una clase "menu" para comprobar que no afectará al cambiar de boton cuando se pulsen, es decir, cada vez que se impriman los menus, ambos obtendrán la misma clase*/
    .menu{
       background-color:green;
       color:red;
     }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        /*Primera funcion para el primer boton*/
        function impMenu1(){
            //Creo un string que contendrá el menu con una clase "menu" en el elemento <ul> para que obtenga los estilos css:
            var stringMenu = `
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li>Elemento Menu 1</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 1</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 1</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 1</li>
                            </ul>`;
            //Añado ese string al <div> cuyo id es "imprimir"
            document.getElementById("imprimir").innerHTML=stringMenu;
            //De esta manera, javacript inserará en el div vacio del final el menú
        }

        /*Segunda funcion para el primer boton*/
        function impMenu2(){
            //Creo un string que contendrá el menu:
            var stringMenu = `
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li>Elemento Menu 2</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 2</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 2</li>
                                <li>Elemento Menu 2</li>
                            </ul>`;
            //Añado ese string al <div> cuyo id es "imprimir"
            document.getElementById("imprimir").innerHTML=stringMenu;
            //De esta manera, javacript inserará en el div vacio del final el menú
        }
    
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Añado los dos botones -->
    <input type="button" onclick="impMenu1()" id="boton1" value="menu1">
    <input type="button" onclick="impMenu2()" id="boton2" value="menu2">

    <!--Cada boton llama a cada funcion de javascript mas arriba declaradas-->

    <br><br>
    <!-- En el siguiente div se imprimirá el resultado-->
    <div id="imprimir"></div>
    <!-- Cada vez que se pulse un boton, el anterior div se sobreescribirá -->
</body>
</html>
```

Con el anterior fragmento de codigo, cada vez que pulses un boton, la funcion sobreescribirá el div del final con un menu nuevo. De esta manera, podrás obtener distintos menus sin importar el estilo que estes utilizando, ya que puedes cambiar el estilo en el css y simplemente editarlo en el string.

Comment: bueno te explico yo tengo dos menu con los mismos estilos css ahora eso no interfiere con la solucion que me comentaste..?

Comment: ok soy nuevo en esto jajaja donde coloco esa opcion por favor ema ayudo

Comment: listo ya la tilde como me dices pero no puedo quitar el negativo hermano

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero la idea del sitio es responder preguntas bien formuladas, no realizar los deberes de otro. El OP no se ha tomado la tarea de mostrar el esfuerzo realizado y tampoco a colocado un [mcve]. Las preguntas como esta no deberían responderse. Tómalo en cuenta para otra oportunidad. Saludos